# SQL query for row values that are in two different queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure this has been answered before but I am not able to find the correct terms to search for to find my answer.

I have a table such as:

```
USERNAME     ACTIONNUM      VALUE1     VALUE2
--------     ----------     ------     ------
Person1      Action1             0          1
Person1      Action1             1          1
Person1      Action1             1          1
Person1      Action2             0          1
Person1      Action2             1          1
Person2      Action3             0          1
Person2      Action3             1          1
Person3      Action4             1          1
```

For this example, I want to perform one search for VALUE1 and VALUE2 of 0,1, giving me just the USERNAME.  So the first search would give: Person1, Person2.

Then, the second search should give me a distinct action number and count the number of times the action exists for values 1,1 BUT only give me rows where the USERNAME was found in the first search.

So for this example, I want the query to return:

```
USERNAME     ACTIONNUM      COUNT
--------     ----------     -----
Person1      Action1            2
Person1      Action2            1
Person2      Action3            1
```

So Person3 is skipped because Person3 does not get returned from the first search

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: So does it not matter if `VALUE1 = 0 AND VALUE2 = 1` is not true on a particular action?  As long as it exists once for a given `USERNAME`?

Comment: I'm very new to SQL so everything I have been trying has not even returned anything.  I basically am able to do each query seperately, so I can return the distinct usernames or each instance of an actionnum.  I have not found any easy solutions to merging these results in the way I want though.

Comment: @user2871467: Does Diver's answer give you the right information?  Or do you need all `ACTIONNUM` even when not matching those values?

Comment: I changed my answer from

select username, actionnum, count(*)
from table
where value1 = 0 and value2 = 1
group by username, actionnum;

to the one below since I misread part of the question.  sqlfiddle attached.

Answer (score 1):

You could use IN from a subquery:

```
select * from table where value1 = 1 and value2 = 1 and username in  (
select username from table where value1 = 0 and value2 = 1
)
```

Comment: This has pretty much solved it!  It has combined the list how I want, and hopefully I can solve the rest of it too.

Answer (score 1):

Changing this answer, I misread part of the question.

```
SELECT username, actionnum, (select count(actionnum)
                             from test1 b
                             where b.value1=1
                             and b.value2=1
                             and b.username = a.username
                             and b.actionnum = a.actionnum)
FROM test1 a
WHERE  value1 = 0 AND value2 = 1
order by 1, 2;
```

see the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3556c/10)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
Select 
  UserName
, ActionNum
, Count(*) As Cnt
From MyTable
    Where Value1 = 1
      And Value2 = 1 
      And UserName In
        ( 
            Select Distinct UserName 
            From MyTable
            Where Value1 = 0
              And Value2 = 1 
        )
Group By
  UserName
, ActionNum
```

Comment: Needs a `GROUP BY` perhaps?

Comment: Now looks correct to me, as far as I can understand the question.  Though it's far from clear what is intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like..

```
SELECT 
    table.USERNAME,
    table.ACTIONNUM,
    COUNT(table.ACTIONNUM) as ACTIONNUMCOUNT
FROM 
    table
WHERE
    table.VALUE1 = 1
    AND
    table.VALUE2 = 1
    AND
    USERNAME IN 
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT USERNAME FROM table where value1 = 0 and value2 = 1
                )
GROUP BY
    table.ACTIONNUM
```